# How do I tell if I'm in the 20 main chunks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

The 20 chunks around the origin of the world are always loaded, whether you are there or not. This makes them a great place to build farms. Is there a way to tell if you are in those 20 chunks or not?
I'm fine with using the debug menu but I'd prefer to avoid having to count chunk borders or something if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *spawn chunks* usually consist of an area of 16×16 chunks centered as close as possible to the world spawn point.
A **compass** will point to the spawn point.

For players not connected to a bed, in *Creative* and *Survival* mode, players spawn on a random block in a 20×20 box centered on the spawn point. The spawn point can be inferred by repeatedly respawning and keeping track of the smallest rectangle encompassing all blocks players have spawned on so far.

And since chunks are 16 × 16 segments of the Minecraft worlds, once you know the spawn point coordinates you can easily find the spawn chunks bounds with math.

Source, [Minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.fandom.com/el/wiki/Spawn_chunk#Finding_spawn_chunks).

Comment: I built a farm in -68, 130.  Is that inside the spawn chunks?

Comment: The spawn point tends to be around 0/0, but can be quite far off, especially if 0/0 is in an ocean biome. As you have 16x16 spawn chunks around the spawn point, it's 8 chunks - 128 blocks - in each direction, which will make z=130 *just* outside. But your spawn point could easily be at z=200, or z=-200, and without tracking the spawn point (by using F3 when you die without a bed, or a mod, or checking level.dat with mcedit, or ...), you can't know if a particular coordinate is in your spawn blocks. Break your bed, die, and if you're less then 100 blocks from your farm, you're ok.

Comment: As an example, seed -2017017060667713728 has its spawn point at 49,-527 - far away from 0/0. You can check this on https://www.chunkbase.com/apps/seed-map#-2017017060667713728, and also upload the level.dat from your own save game there to see your own spawn point.

Comment: the compass goes to .8, 1.7